# How to start adobe air application automatically when the android device boots?

Tags: android, air

I have written an application using Adobe Air 3.4 SDK. I have deployed it to my android v4.0.4 device. It works fine (in full screen mode as expected).

Now the application is expected to run in full screen mode automatically before the device shows the native android screen to the user.

How can I do this? Suggestions anyone?

Answer (score 0):

In the AIR native classes, there is a thing called startAtLogin that you can set to true or false :

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.startAtLogin = true;
```

But I doubt that can be used to override the native android screen and be displayed before it.
I suppose some built-in checks have been made to be sure nothing gets booted before the screen is ready and diplayed.

Still, you can try it :-)